# Store files in C# EXE file

Tags: c#, file, executable

It is actually useful for me to store some files in EXE to copy to selected location.
I'm generating HTML and JS files and need to copy some CSS, JS and GIFs.

Snippet

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyFile.bin", ProjectNamespace.Properties.Resources.MyFile);

doesn't work for me!

On "WriteAllBytes" it says:
"cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[]'"
for image and
"cannot convert from 'string' to 'byte[]'"
for text file.

Help!

UPDATE: Solved below.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, click the green check mark beside the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add files to project resources and set their "Build Action" as "Embedded Resource".

Now extract any file (text or binary) using this snippet:

```
WriteResourceToFile("Project_Namespace.Resources.filename_as_in_resources.extension", "extractedfile.txt");


public static void WriteResourceToFile(string resourceName, string fileName)
{
    int bufferSize = 4096; // set 4KB buffer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (Stream input = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        int byteCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (byteCount > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            byteCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know how deep is it correct according to this article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html
but it works.

Answer (score 7):

Add the files you want to your solution and then set their `Build Action` property to `Embedded Resource`. This will embed the file into your exe. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(VS.80).aspx))

Then you just need to write the code to write the file out to disk when the exe is executed.

Something like:

```
File.Copy("resource.bmp", @"C:\MyFile.bin");
```

Replace `resource.bmp` with your file name.

**Addendum:**

If you keep the file in a sub-folder in your solution you need to make the sub-folder part of the path to `resource.bmp`. Eg:

```
File.Copy(@"NewFolder1\resource.bmp", @"C:\MyFile.bin");
```

Also, you may need to set the `Copy To Output Directory` property to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer`.

Comment: You right, it must be "Embedded Resource", but just File.Copy() doesn't work here.
I found the solution.

Comment: It works for me... Did you change the "resource.bmp" to the right file name?

Comment: Shure. But it doesn't.
Seems that File.Copy() works only with textfiles.

I left my solution here.

Comment: What happens if you don't copy a text file? I tried the above with a bmp.

Comment: Don't know. I post my universal solution below and it works with any kind of file. Easy as copy&paste + set a "Build Action".

Comment: Ehh, man... I tried exactly as you described and your solution DOESN'T work for me. Then I found out how to do it an post my solution below. It is 100% working with any kind of file — binary and text. Now my tiny, yeah, very tiny and quite unnecessary problem SOLVED. There is too much to do ahead. BTW I took a look. FileNotFound exception pops on file: File.Copy("somefile.gif", someDestPath); Even if as Project_Namespace.Resources.somefile.gif Yeah, file IS embedded and it is framework 2.0

Comment: A FileNotFound exception? Did you put the files into a sub-folder in your solution?

Comment: Ok, then in this case you need to reflect that in your path to the source file. I've updated the answer in case somebody else comes across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you added the files through the Project Properties window. That does not allow you to add an arbitrary file but it does support TextFiles, Bitmaps and so on.

For an embedded TextFile, use

```
  File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MyFile.bin", Properties.Resources.TextFile1);
```

For an Image, use

```
  Properties.Resources.Image1.Save(@"C:\MyFile.bin");
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* embed binary files in a .resx file. Put them in the **Files** section (it looks like you used the **Images** section instead). It should be accessible as an array of bytes if your .resx file generates a .Designer.cs file.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\foobar.exe", Properties.Resources.foobar);
```